# How to execute stored procedure cursor records parallelly

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, parallel-processing

I have a stored procedure which does following tasks on 2 tables related to each other as below

```
CREATE TABLE address (adr_id, ver_id, address) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 'newYork' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, 'newYork' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 3, 'newYork' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 1, 'Washington' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 2, 'Washington' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE employee (emp_id,adr_id,ver_id,) AS
SELECT 100,1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 200,1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 300,1, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 400,4, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 500,4, 2 FROM DUAL;
```

Here Following tasks are done in stored procedure and required to be executed in parallel as to increase throughput on billions of records in both table

**Note: Foreign key Constraints are relaxed**

1. Find records with distinct address "newYork" and have them in cursor
2. Loop on Cursor record as follows
3. and process each address record select * from address where address ="newYork"
4. Insert a new record in Address table with same address as first record (with ver_id=0) in #3 and take the newly inserted id
5. Find parent table records based on foreign key in Employee table and update them with newly id mentioned in #4.
6. delete all records of #3

Since Step 2 to 6 can be executed in parallel just wanted to know how this can be achieved ?

### Expected After

**Address**

| adr_id | ver_id | address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 0 | newYork |
| 12 | 0 | Washington |

**Employee**

| id | adr_id | ver_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 11 | 1 |
| 200 | 11 | 2 |
| 300 | 11 | 3 |
| 400 | 12 | 1 |
| 500 | 12 | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

As a frame challenge, do not update the `adr_id` and just change the version; that way you do not need to change the referential constraints.

```sql
MERGE INTO address dst
USING (
  SELECT ROWID AS rid,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY adr_id) AS cnt,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY adr_id ORDER BY ver_id) AS rn
  FROM   address
) src
ON (dst.ROWID = src.rid AND src.cnt > 1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET ver_id = 0
  DELETE WHERE src.rn > 1
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5fTQ1xSp)

Comment: Actually there is a dependency hence I can not touch ver_id in parent table as one more entity e.g phones like address in current system . But how will it work for billions of records are you are suggesting to execute this as is and oracle will execute this in parallel internally ? Will not this hang I think it will as it have aggregate and order by clause .